# How do I set limited generic return type

Tags: java, android

Taking the following 2 objects, I cant figure out how to make the following work.

```
public final *Generic SubType* getInfo(){
...
}
```

First the class I am working with

```
public class ResultEntry<Type extends ResultType>{

    private final Type mType;
    private final String mLabel;
    private final String mInfo;

    private ResultEntry(final Type t, final String label, final String info){
        mType = t;
        mLabel = label;
        mInfo = info;
    }

    public static ResultEntry<ResultType> newInstance(final String label, final Number info){
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.NUMBER, label, info.toString());
    }

    public static ResultEntry<ResultType> newInstance(final String label, final Boolean info){
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.NUMBER, label, info.toString());
    }

    public static ResultEntry<ResultType> newInstance(final String label, final String info){
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.NUMBER, label, info);
    }

    public final ResultType getType(){
        return mType;
    }

    public final String getLabel(){
        return mLabel;
    }

    public final *Generic SybType* getInfo(){

    }

}
```

And then enum ResultType

```
public enum ResultType {

    STRING  ("STRING"),
    BOOLEAN ("BOOLEAN"),
    NUMBER  ("NUMBER");

    private final String s;

    ResultType(final String string){
        s = string;
    }

    public final boolean isString(){
        return s.equals(STRING.s);
    }

    public final boolean isBoolean(){
        return s.equals(BOOLEAN.s);
    }

    public final boolean isNumber(){
        return s.equals(NUMBER.s);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is have a way to check what mType is (String, Boolean, or Number) and then return that actual object. Something like,

```
public final *Generic SubType* getInfo(){
    if(mType.isString()) return new String();
    if(mType.isNumber()) return new Number();
    if(mType.isBoolean()) return new Boolean();
}
```

Though obviously I would have actual information to pass back instead.

But I dont know if that is possible, and if so, I don't know how I would go about doing it. It does appear that Android is able to do it via [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).

For reference, I found most of this from [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23957858/limiting-generic-type)

Comment: You can't. The actual type of the return value is determined at **runtime**, from the `mType` value, so how can you specify the return type at **compile time**? The only way to specify the generic return type, is to declare another type parameter for `ResultEntry`.

Comment: So, to clarify, you are saying that I cannot have a sort of "Semi Generic" return type? 

I can return a pure generic, so I guess I figured it would stand to reason that I could return a "Semi Generic" type.

Comment: Remember that `STRING` is not a subtype of `ResultType`. It's an instance of `ResultType`. So if you say `ResultEntry<ResultType.STRING>`, the `Type` parameter is `ResultType`, not `STRING`.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good point. So maybe I need to think about this in another way. My thought process was, check what Instance of ResultType I have, and then return that object type. 

Do you have any recommendations on what I can change, or where I can look that might help me with that? I am trying to avoid having multiple object types and I would rather not have multiple methods to return the same data via casting

Comment: Why do you want a semi generic `getInfo()` method in the first place (which has effectively `Object` as return type)?  Some visitor/ double dispatch pattern often helps to solve issues like this. Instead of having the caller of `getInfo` apply different strategies to the result based on it's type, let the different results implement that logic themselves. E.g. https://gist.github.com/zapl/b268937b63d196329378e6d2ade1e668

Comment: Because for this particular object, it is just a data holder. The only thing it will do is hold data given to it view a larger Result class. I dont like mixing logic. This is just the data, and the logic is done elsewhere. The reason is because who knows what this will hold. It could be any number of things, and will be used by at least 10 different classes. 

The different results do the logic, but they I figured I would remove the step of casting, as it can be done here, if I do it right, as the answer below shows. Thank you though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you do it like this, which doesn't convert the `info` values to String, i.e. `mInfo` is `Object`, not `String`.

```
public class ResultEntry<R> {

    private final ResultType mType;
    private final String mLabel;
    private final Object mInfo;

    private ResultEntry(final ResultType t, final String label, final Object info) {
        this.mType = t;
        this.mLabel = label;
        this.mInfo = info;
    }

    public static ResultEntry<Number> newInstance(final String label, final Number info) {
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.NUMBER, label, info);
    }

    public static ResultEntry<Boolean> newInstance(final String label, final Boolean info) {
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.BOOLEAN, label, info);
    }

    public static ResultEntry<String> newInstance(final String label, final String info) {
        return new ResultEntry<>(ResultType.STRING, label, info);
    }

    public final ResultType getType() {
        return this.mType;
    }

    public final String getLabel() {
        return this.mLabel;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public final R getInfo() {
        return (R) this.mInfo;
    }

}
```

Then you use it like this:

```
ResultEntry<Number>  numEntry  = ResultEntry.newInstance("", 5);
ResultEntry<Boolean> boolEntry = ResultEntry.newInstance("", true);
ResultEntry<String>  strEntry  = ResultEntry.newInstance("", "Foo");

Number  numInfo  = numEntry.getInfo();
Boolean boolInfo = boolEntry.getInfo();
String  strInfo  = strEntry.getInfo();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I was close, Generics just are completely new to me so I was using it wrong.